# simplest way to pass arguments to execve syscall

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

Supposedly, it is very simple to pass arguments to an execve syscall.

In a tutorial, the instructor  says it's only in one line, and leave this as an exercise.

The code below executes "ls" command. And I'm trying to execute something like "ls -la".
After searching and searching, I still have no idea where to add the "-la" !

I know it's in the structure pointed to by the ecx register, and that it has to be null terminated. For now, ecx contains an address to /bin/ls . Should the arguments be another address ?   argv is an array, with first element being "/bin/ls"...

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
        xor eax, eax
        push eax

        push 0x736c2f6e 
        push 0x69622f2f ; //bin/ls

        mov ebx, esp

        push eax
        mov edx, esp

        push ebx
        mov ecx, esp

        mov al, 11
        int 0x80
```

This is not working :

```
xor eax, eax
push eax
push 0x2a632020
push 0x736c2f6e 
push 0x69622f2f ; /bin/ls  c*
mov ecx, esp
```

Comment: Yes, it should be a separate string, separately null terminated and its own address inserted into the `argv` array that so far only has `{ "//bin/ls", NULL }`

Comment: ok, but ecx points to //bin/ls as the first argument.   How can I add a second item to the array, like "-la" ?

Comment: `ecx` points to `argv` which is currently `{ "//bin/ls", NULL }` as I already said. You insert your `-la` to make it look like `{ "//bin/ls", "-la", NULL }`

Comment: That's what I'm trying  to do, in nasm.  How can I insert "-la" ?   ecx points to //bin/ls in memory.  How can I add a second element to that array ?   There's no "array" in assembly.   If ecx points to a memory address, is it the memory address of the full argv, or is it just the first element in argv ?

Comment: Yes it's the first element of `argv` which itself is a pointer to `"//bin/ls"`.

Comment: But how do I add "-la" ?  As a seperate memory reference to the stack ?

Comment: Which part is causing you problem? First put the string itself on the stack (null terminated) then add that address into the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200428/discussion-between-trogne-and-jester).

Comment: You should be using `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`.

Comment: @Jason What?? `syscall` is for x86_64, `int 0x80` is for x86. If he was writing 64-bit code, then `syscall` would be correct, but for 32-bit code `int 0x80` is correct.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My mistake, I didn't know the author was explicitly using x86 instead of x86-64.

Comment: No worries, it's not like I've never overlooked anything similar `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must save the `-la` argument in the `ecx` register and copy it to the `esp` register (I mean in the stack)

```
push eax
push byte 0x61
push word 0x6c2d 
mov ecx, esp ; -la
```

The following is your modified code :

```
global _start

section .text
_start:

xor eax, eax

push eax
push byte 0x61
push word 0x6c2d    
mov ecx, esp ; -la

push eax
push 0x736c2f6e
push 0x69622f2f ; //bin/ls
mov ebx, esp

push edx
push ecx
push ebx
mov ecx, esp

mov al, 11
int 0x80
```

The code working fine :)

```
% ./list
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x 1 febri febri 512 Oct  5 07:45 list
%
```

Comment: Except that is not `ls -la`. What you have is `ls -l`. You would need to remove `push 0x61` and `push 0x6c2d` and replace them with a single `push 0x006c612d`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin if u familiar with `shellcode`, it's avoid `null-bytes`, u can test with `strace`, the result is `ls -la`

Comment: That's why you make sure it is the last byte `:)`  Give it a try.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ahhhh, okay, it's `ls -l`, sorry about it :D

Comment: Sure, no problem, made me think working through it. All a good exercise.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i'm just edit my answer, i think it's correct :D, the result is `ls -la` with no `null-bytes`

Comment: Yep, that's it. Good job.

Comment: You should use character literals like `'//bi'` instead of numeric hex literals.  This is NASM where they Just Work as expected, not a stupid assembler like MASM that reverses them or does weird things.

Comment: Also, `ls` accepts redundant single-letter options so you could `push -lla`.  Or in a case where you did need to get an odd-length string, `push '--la'` / `shr dword [esp], 8` or whatever.   Or store a `0` from AL to insert a terminator.  But yes, push imm8 / push word imm16 also works.  But remember that `push byte 0x61` still pushes a dword; NASM should really reject the `byte` keyword there because it's not a valid operand-size for push.  `push strict byte 'a'` would tell it that you definitely want the `push imm8` encoding, but you'll get that anyway with `push 'a'` or `push dword 'a'`.

Comment: @PeterCordes, character literals like '//bi' is not working in my nasm. Probably because it's an old version, NASM version 2.09.10 compiled on Oct 17 2011.

Comment: @trogne: Character literals are not new.  NASM syntax hasn't changed a lot over time.  A copy of the manual for [NASM 0.98](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoc1.html) from before it supported SSE instructions [documents character constants](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.2), with the example of `mov eax,'abcd'`.  If `push '//bi'` doesn't work, you're doing it wrong.  It assembles to `68 2F2F6269` for me.  (It's not plausible that the NASM 2.09.10 release has a bug with character constants.  That would have been noticed.)

Comment: If it's supposed to work, why this works :         
        `push 0x68732f6e
        push 0x69622f2f`, but not `push 'hs/n'
        push 'ib//'`

Comment: @trogne Do not reverse order the string `hs/n` and `ib//`, `push dword "/bin"` and `push dword "//sh"` or `mov dword [esp+4], "/bin"` and `mov dword [esp+4], "//sh"` it's work btw.

Comment: This works : `push "//sh"`, then `push "/bin"`,     but this not work : `mov dword [esp+4], "//sh"`, then `mov dword [esp+4], "/bin"`, because it just moves to the same place on the stack, 4 bytes from the top (2nd mov replacing previous mov)

Comment: mov solution : `mov dword [esp], "/bin"`, `mov dword [esp+4], "//sh"`, `mov byte [esp+8], al`,   last mov because first mov overwrite my null byte (push solution was pushing on top of my null byte)